# Is it possible to specify testApplicationId per flavor in Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have two product flavors, and set the `testApplicationId` like so in `build.gradle`:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 19
    testApplicationId 'com.example.testapp'
}
```

Is it possible to override this `testApplicationId` in each `productFlavor`?

I tried overriding the `testApplicationId` itself in the individual `productFlavors`, but then the `R.class` file doesn't get generated, and I get a compile error.

I read about the `packageName`/`applicationId` not affecting the `R.class` file, but I'm not sure if that rule holds for the `testApplicationId` too.

Comment: I'm trying to do this myself. It should be possible, since you can specify an applicationId per flavor. However, I'm having an issue with Gradle complaining that I haven't specified my applicationId even though I've clearly put it into the build file...

Comment: Just opened bug on [Android](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72255) dev-tools.

Comment: Have you tried using a test manifest that explicitly sets applicationId in XML instead of gradle?

Answer (score 1):

I verify this works as expected in Android Gradle Plugin version `2.3.0`

```
defaultConfig {
    ...   
    testApplicationId 'default'
}

productFlavors {
    first {
        testApplicationId 'first'
    }
    second {
        testApplicationId 'second'
    }
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.productFlavors.each {
        def buildType = variant.buildType.name.capitalize()
        println "$it.name$buildType $it.testApplicationId"
    }
}
```

Give following output:

```
firstDebug first
firstRelease first
secondDebug second
secondRelease second
```